# Angular 2 - Getting object id from array and displaying data

Tags: json, angular, typescript, object

I currently have a service that gets an array of json objects from a json file which displays a list of leads. Each lead has an id and when a lead within this list is clicked it takes the user to a view that has this id in the url ie ( /lead/156af71250a941ccbdd65f73e5af2e67 )

I've been trying to get this object by id through my leads service but just cant get it working. Where am I going wrong?

Also, i'm using two way binding in my html.

SERVICE

```
  leads;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAllLeads() {
    return this.http.get('../../assets/leads.json').map((response) => response);
  }

  getLead(id: any) {
    const leads = this.getAllLeads();
    const lead = this.leads.find(order => order.id === id);
    return lead;
  }
```

COMPONENT

```
  lead = {};

  constructor(
    private leadService: LeadService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) {

      const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
      if (id) { this.leadService.getLead(id).take(1).subscribe(lead => this.lead = lead); }

   }
```

JSON

```
[
  {
    "LeadId": "156af71250a941ccbdd65f73e5af2e66",
    "LeadTime": "2016-03-04T10:53:05+00:00",
    "SourceUserName": "Fred Dibnah",
    "LeadNumber": "1603041053",
  },
  {
    "LeadId": "156af71250a999ccbdd65f73e5af2e67",
    "LeadTime": "2016-03-04T10:53:05+00:00",
    "SourceUserName": "Harry Dibnah",
    "LeadNumber": "1603021053",
  },
  {
    "LeadId": "156af71250a999ccbdd65f73e5af2e68",
    "LeadTime": "2016-03-04T10:53:05+00:00",
    "SourceUserName": "John Doe",
    "LeadNumber": "1603021053",
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't used the newly created `leads` array (`const leads` is not `this.leads`), so do this:

```
getLead(id: any) {
    return this.getAllLeads().find(order => order.LeadId === id);
}
```

And change your `map` to `flatMap`, because from the server you get an array, but you have to transform it to a stream of its items:

```
getAllLeads() {
    return this.http.get('../../assets/leads.json').flatMap(data => data);
}
```

Don't forget to import it if you have to: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/flatMap';`

Comment: I'm getting the error Property 'find' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'

Comment: @DBoi You have to import `find`: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/find';`

Comment: Thanks Roland. i'm now getting this error on the first 'id' - Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Object' even though my ILead model has an id:string;

Comment: @DBoi Even if your `ILead` model has `id`, are you sure that the object has? In your JSON file you have `LeadId`. Try this: `order.LeadId === id`. If this is not the issue, try to log your object to check what's the problem with it.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm still getting the same error using LeadId. Have I mapped it correctly in the getAllLeads function? Its logging the array in the console if I do .map((response) => console.log(response));

Comment: I think, I know the problem now: in your `getAllLeads` method change `map` to `flatMap` (with the same parameter). It should work. I update my answer too.

Comment: thanks Roland, just in case you need to update your answer... I had to import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';

Comment: Getting the following error: Argument of type '(data: Object) => Object' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Object, index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
  Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.
    The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
      Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'ArrayLike<{}>'.
        The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
          Property 'length' is missing in type 'Object'.

Comment: You should play with `console.log` in your `getAllLeads()` too to check the issue. Maybe try something like this: `.flatMap((data: any[]) => data)`.

Comment: That worked. Thanks so much for taking the time to help - its much appreciated. Also learnt something new - mergeMap!

Answer (score 1):

You can have getLead in your component level itself since you are not making any api to get the information. In your component,

```
this.lead = this.leads.find(order => order.id === id);
```

or to make the above service work, just do **`leads`** instead of **`this.leads`**

```
 const lead = leads.find(order => order.id === id);
```

Comment: im getting the error Property 'find' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'

Comment: in my getAllLeads function?

Comment: are you referring to my JSON set up?